# No output in cmd script to merge batch file contents

Tags: cmd, merge

In a windows cmd I am running an exe command like:

```
for %F in ("*.fa") do  "../program.exe" -input %F -output %F.fasta| type %F %F.fasta > %F.txt
```

Here, say in the current folder, there are three input files as:

```
x.fa
y.fa
z.fa
```

The file content of `x.fa` is:

```
hi
```

the file content of auto-generated `x.fasta` is:

```
all
```

What I want is to generate a final `.txt` file (here `x.txt`) that will contain:

```
hi
all
```

but although I get the `.fasta` file (filecontent ->all), in the final `.txt` file I only get the content of `.fa` file (filecontent ->hi).

What's wrong in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%F` in your code always expands to the full filename: `x.fa`, `y.fa` or `z.fa`

So `%F.fasta` will be expanded to `x.fa.fasta`, `y.fa.fasta`, `z.fa.fasta`

and `%F.txt` will be expanded to `x.fa.txt` and so on.

To get the filename without extension you should use `%~dpnF`, for example `%~dpnF.txt` or `%~dpnF.fasta`

In addition you should use the copy command to concatenate files:

```
copy %F + %~dpnF.fasta %dpnF.txt
```

The full script would look like:

```
for %F in ("*.fa") do  "../program.exe" -input %F -output %~dpnF.fasta| copy %F + %~dpnF.fasta %dpnF.txt
```

You will find the full explanation of the `for` command variable expansions at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900.aspx#Anchor_2

PS.: please take care that the name of variables inside a script file (.cmd or .bat) have to be preceeded by `%%` instead of `%`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `|` you are creating a pipe, and the commands on both sides of the pipe are **executed concurrently**, with the standard output stream of the command in the left side piped into the standard input stream of the command in the right side.

So, you start to execute the `type` before the `program.exe` ends, so the `.fasta` file has not been generated and `type` can not read its contents.

Just concatenate the commands with `&` to execute the `type` after `program.exe` ends.

```dos
                                                               v
for %F in (*.fa) do  ..\program.exe -input %F -output %F.fasta & type %F %F.fasta > %F.txt
                                                               ^
```